# In the wso2 developers portal which files contain the code segment(s) responsible for generating the gateway URLs?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm working on a small change to the wso2 developers portal. When we import a API to the wso2 dev portal it generates gateway URLs to that API thinking its an API created in the wso2 publisher. But what if we want to import an API from AWS and in such cases the generated URLs by the dev portal will be incorrect. To fix this issue I'm having trouble finding the code segments responsible for this. If you guys have any idea please let me know. thanks in advance [image: Screenshot of the wso2 dev portal gateway URLs generated for the CalculatorAPI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URLs are static value, then you can hard-code it in the code level. `Environments.jsx`, resides in `<APIM-Home>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devportal/source/src/app/components/Apis/Details/` the directory contains the source code that renders under `Gateway Environments` section (From line starting from [203](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.6.163/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.store.feature/src/main/resources/devportal/source/src/app/components/Apis/Details/Environments.jsx#L203)).

Comment: hi thanks for this. but do you know where the gateway urls are generated?

Comment: @AkshithaDalpethado, these URLs are constructed based on the configurations given in deployment.toml under `[[apim.gateway.environment]]` section. You can get more information from this [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/publish-api/publish-through-multiple-api-gateways/).

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint URLs are generated from the defined gateway environment. You can define a new gateway environment with AWS HTTP or HTTPS endpoints. So in dev portals, it will append the particular API's context and version to the endpoint and display here. If the expected gateway URLs are different from the `protocol://GW_host:GW_port/context/version` then you can do some additional changes from the UI. So that you can change the dev portal react code and apply the changes.